# split complex string

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have a string like this:

```
1|f1|</a1|a2/></a3|a4/>|f2
```

I want to split by '|' by java
but I need to ignore `</` and `/>`. How can I do this? Seems like a regexp approach this

the above string should split into:

1

f1

a1|a2

a3|a4

f2

Comment: What do you need to ignore? What have you tried already?

Comment: i tried by regular splitting and tokenize, but i want to implement this by regex it should be faster than regular splitting

Comment: Is your string always correct? I mean is every `</` have also `/>`? Can they be nested like `</X</Y/>Z/>`?

Comment: no, no nested always same structure , Thank you.

Comment: What gave you the impression that a regex would be faster than regular splitting?  Regex is almost never the best approach with regards to performance.  Regexes are nice for their convenience and flexibility, not their performance.

Comment: yes, but tokenize and then splitting consuming memory over than regex, specially in complex structure like this.

Comment: Greater complexity tends to exacerbate the problems with regexes, not alleviate them.  There is a lot of processing and backtracking that goes on behind the scenes to make regexes work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`split` method uses regex as parameter and `|` in regex is special character which means OR. To make it normal character place `\\` before it like

```
"yourString".split("\\|");
```

In your case you would need also [look-ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html#lookahead) mechanism so your regex can look like

```
/></|(/>)?\\|(?=[^>]*(</|$))(</)?
```

It will split on

- `/></`
- `|` with optional `/>` before or `</` after it BUT ONLY if there will be no `>` after it until `</` or end of your input `$`. This will guarantee that `|` is outside of `</ />`

Also to get rid of problems in situations like `"</a|b/>|c|</d|e/>"` where `</` is at start and `/>` at the end of your input you need to remove them before split.

It seems necessary because we don't want to produce empty String as first or last element in produced array like in case `"ab".split("a")` which will produce `{"", "b"}`

Lets test it:

```
for (String s : "</a0|b0/>|1|f1|</a1|a2/></a3|a4/>|f2|</a5|a6/>"
        .replaceAll("^</", "").split("/></|/>$|(/>)?\\|(?=[^>]*(</|$))(</)?")) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

output:

```
a0|b0
1
f1
a1|a2
a3|a4
f2
a5|a6
```

Comment: @BassemAly didn't you mean to accept this one, not my answer?

Comment: Note: if the first or last token in the input is a `</a5|a6/>` type, this will not quite work. For example: `</a5|a6/>|1|f1|</a1|a2/></a3|a4/>|f2` produces `</a5|a6, 1, f1, a1|a2, a3|a4, f2`.

Comment: @alan i like your answer as well, thanks all for your quick answers

Comment: @BassemAly In that cases you just need to first remove `</` at start and `/>` at the end of your input string. You can do it with `replaceAll("^</|/>$", "")`.

Answer (score 2):

You could try the following Regex which uses negative [look ahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).

```
(?!</[^\|]*)[\|](?![^\|]*/>)
```

This works out as:

`[\|]` matches occurrences of `|`

`(?!</[^\|]*)` states that said matches must not be preceded by `</sometext`

`(?![^\|]*/>)` states that said matches must not be followed by `sometext/>`

Note: in the above example `sometext` is zero or more characters which are not a `|`

Comment: it gives me `[1, f1, </a1|a2/></a1|a2/>, f1]`

Comment: That would be because your input string has no `|` between `</a1|a2/></a1|a2/>`. Do you want it to split these as well?

Comment: In Java "look behind" must be finite so `*` is not an option (I know, it is painful), but we can use fact that if there is `</` there must also be `/>` so look-ahead is enough.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know Java had that limitation.

Answer (score 1):

this regex should match. imma leave a list of possible things to try if one fails go to the next. The first one is \b should escape word bound but java might need to not escape the escape backslash so i added a second one. If both those fail move to the last one. This one says that it must be a letter between capital A to common z. There should be not option now for any spaces what so ever.

The end result for the last one is match:

"<" any character, multiple time,">" if that fails then

match:

any character that is a letter or number

```
"(<.*?>|[^|\\b]*)" "(<.*?>|[^|\b]*)" "(<.*?>|[A-z0-9]*)"

public String[] methodName(String s)
{
ArrayList<String>list= new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p=Pattern.compile("(<.*?>|[^|]*)");
Matcher match=p.matcher(s);
while(match.find())
{
 list.add(match.group());
}
String[] listArray= new String[list.size()];
return listArray.toArray(listArray);
}
```

remember to vote if it helps
cheers mate

Comment: Have you tried it? Gives me incorrect result: `[1, , f1, , </a1, , a2/></a3, , a4/>, , f2, ]`

Comment: i've updated and tested it should work fine now, sorry about that

Comment: Still not quite. This produces `1, , f1, , </a1|a2/>, </a3|a4/>, ,f2, `

Comment: is this java you are testing this in? there are no spaces in the String don't see why it would match spaces? plus how come no spaces between </a1|a2/> </a3|a4/>
I was assuming the string above posted in the question was used

Comment: @Lpc_dark I ran your code in Java (after fixing the list to array line), and then printed the results like so: `for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) System.out.print(list[i] + ", ");`. For some reason it seems that the code is returning some empty matches.

Comment: Kk I will give it a more in depth look in 30 I think I have an idea

Comment: If all the values are letters and number except for the bracket ones I could say match only letters and numbers. Instead of not "|" should save us from the space problem. It might be a word bound its matching as well. Hence why the space for each item.

Comment: i updated it with a few things that should work if not will run it later. don't have time to run it now